# Testar se um input do tipo radiobutton é seleccionado em PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Eu criei uma tabela que é o resumo de todos os meus cálculos anteriores e nessa tabela criei um campo onde coloquei um input radial para poder selecionar uma das opções calculadas. Preciso identificar qual dos inputs foi clicado, utilizando do id, para prosseguir com os cálculos. Estou utilizando a linguagem PHP.

Tabela:

```
            <table class="table table-bordered">
            <caption> Calculation </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Cam number</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Space between cam</th>
                        <th class="text-center">FOV</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Overlap</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Height</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Pixels</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Selected</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$ncam" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$dist mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$fov mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$ov mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$alt mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$sensor" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="row-3" id="l1" data-col="1"></td>

                 </tr>
                <tr>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$ncam1" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$dist1 mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$fov1 mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$ov1 mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$alt1 mm" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><?php echo"$sensor" ?></td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" id="l2" ></td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>
```

Então depois a ideia era seleccionar uma ou outra opção e os cálculos serem "automáticos".

Obrigado.

---

Fiz a alteração aqui :[Teste do Script usando radio imput](http://jsfiddle.net/17b092vt/3/)

Aqui o script funciona, mas se colocar no meu documento deixa de funcionar, não estou a entender o porquê.

---

Neste momento estou a tentar passar a variável do input radial, para uma variável em PHP e estou a ter um erro. Neste momento não sei de onde pode surgir este erro, pois estou a passar a variável correctamente:

```
$escolha = $_POST['radio'];
```

Não sei se o problema é devido a ter dois forms na mesma página, só me falta resolver este problema para terminar.
Obrigado

Comment: no input usa o mesmo name para todos os radio's assim apenas um poderá ser selecionado e apos o submit é enviado o value desse radio selecionado

Comment: Ninguém tem ideia de como posso fazer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para recuperar o valor deste input é necessário colocar esta tabela dentro de uma tag form.

```
<form action="processa-tabela.php" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="escolha" value="l"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="escolha" value="2"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit">Enviar</input>
</form>
```

No arquivo `processa-tabela.php` você irá receber a variável assim:

```
$idEscolha = $_POST['escolha'];
```

Como você não adicionou explicitamente um input radio indicando como selecionado.

```
<input type="radio" name="escolha" value="l" selected>
```

Se o usuário não selecionar, a variável não vai existir, para evitar esse problema, verifique se a variável existe e faça o tratamento para quando não existir, ou simplesmente adicione a primeira linha sempre como selecionado.

Para verificar se a váriável exite faça:

```
if (isset($_POST['escolha']) === false) {
    // Executa o tratamento de quando não existir
    // pode ser uma mensagem informando que é obrigatório
    // selecionar uma opção.
} else {
    // Executa o calculo quando existir
}
```

Comment: Antes de mais obrigado, em vez de ir para outra pagina, pretendo manter-me na mesma. Para isso retiro o parâmetro action e depois para receber a variável escrevo:                                                                                   if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST")
    {$idEscolha = $_POST['escolha'];}

Comment: Tranquilo ;) Mas mesmo se for enviar para a mesma página, é importante manter o action, pois é um atributo obrigatório para a tag `form` no HTML. Trabalhar no mesmo arquivo já é uma escolha sua.

Comment: Então o parâmetro action fica Vazio? Algo como action=""  ? A minha ideia em usar o imput radial é para o utilizar como "submit", ou seja, selecciono uma ou outra opção. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Não, coloca o nome ou a URL do mesmo arquivo. Deixar links, formulário, etc, sem um destino definido pode gerar alguns problemas com algumas versões de navegadores.

Comment: Olá, estou com um pequeno problema. Estou a tentar colocar desta forma. Mas apesar de funcionar, recebo sempre uma mensagem que a variável não existe. E quando envio refresca tudo pedindo novamente os dados, como ja foram inseridos fica cheio de mensagens de erro. Como posso contornar esta situação? Obrigado.

Comment: não entendi direito sua dúdiva @PedroLima, qual variávelta dando como não existente? Se já foi inserido uma vez o cara deve abrir a mesma página editando o dado existente? Se for só inserir recomendo colocar o processamento em outro arquivo, e no final do processo coloca `header('Location: arquivo.php');` assim se o cara atualizar o formuláiro não vai ficar processando sempre ou ficar aparecendo a mensagem de que dados foram enviados.

Answer (score 3):

EM primeiro, lugar, vamos considerar a seguinte regra:

> **Radio Button**: Para selecionar somente um valor (é mantido o mesmo *name* para todos os inputs, o que muda é o valor.
>   **Checkbox**: Usado para múltipla seleções. O name e o valor são variáveis.

Para o propósito que você precisa, use checkbox. Mesmo que tenha que selecionar somente um item, é possível marcar/desmarcar, enquanto o radio, por padrão, não atende essa funcionalidade.

Agora para selecionar somente uma das opções com checkbox, você pode fazer dessa maneira:

#### HTML

```
<input id="chkCamp1" type="checkbox" data-check="1" value="elemento 1"> elemento 1
<input id="chkCamp2" type="checkbox" data-check="2" value="elemento 2"> elemento 2
<input type="text" data-view>
```

#### SCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $('[data-check]').on('click', function() {
        var myInput = {valor: $(this).val(), id: $(this).data('check')};
        $('[data-check]').each(function(index, value) {
            ($(this).data('check') == myInput.id) ?
             $(this).attr('checked', true) :
             $(this).attr('checked', false);
             $('[data-view]').val(myInput.valor);
        });
    });
});
```

## Confira aqui a seleção de chechbox

Para selecionar usando radio, não é necessário, script para limitar a quantidade de seleção, mas por padrão ele não é desabilitado, isso pode ser feito usando script:

#### HTML

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
            <caption> Calculation </caption>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                        <th class="text-center">Cam number</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Space between cam</th>
                        <th class="text-center">FOV</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Overlap</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Height</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Pixels</th>
                        <th class="text-center">Selected</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">000</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 px</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="row-3" id="l1" class="rdo" value="1"></td>

                 </tr>
                 <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">000</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 mm</td>
                        <td class="text-center">000 px</td>
                        <td class="text-center"><input type="radio" name="row-3" id="l2" value="2"  class="rdo" ></td>
                 </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>
                <label>Valor:</label>
               <input type="text" id="saida">
```

#### SCRIPT

```
$(function() {
    $('.rdo').on('click', function() {
       $('#saida').val( $(this).val() );
    });
});
```

## Confira aqui a seleção com radion button

Comment: Antes de mais obrigado, consigo entender a mensagem. Se usar check boxes tenho sempre a oportunidade de voltar a não ter nenhuma opção seleccionada. É um aspecto interessante e não tinha pensado nisso. Eu estou a pensar em usar uma destas duas abordagens para efectuar o submit em vez de seleccionar e depois carregar em submit. Essa era a ideia, carregava directamente na linha pretendida e o programa continuava, sem obrigatoriamente ter de carregar num botão submit.

Comment: Estou a tentar aplicar o seu código ao meu programa, já adicionei a classe assim como o value. Depois adicionei o Script no body, mas não consigo obter o mesmo resultado que apresenta.

Comment: @PedroLima, não esqueça de incluir a biblioteca do jquery.

Comment: Eu coloquei a biblioteca mas não estava a funcionar. Tive de fazer o download e colocar na aplicação. Agora só preciso saber como enviar a minha escolha sem ter de carregar submit. Carregando apenas ou num, ou noutro, o programa enviar os dados da tabela e efectuar logo o resto dos calculos.